# Trying to minimize duplicate code in a loop

Tags: java, java-stream

I'm converting my java for loop that I wrote into a java stream, The for loop had duplicate code that I think can be fixed with a stream, This is what I had going on, on my old loop.

```
    try (DirectoryStream<Path> stream = Files.newDirectoryStream(path)) {
        for (Path entry : stream) {
            String fileName = entry.getFileName().toString();
            if (Files.isDirectory(entry)) {
                grepFilesAndFolders(entry);
            } else if (shouldChange(entry)) {
                //Doing all the foreach work here
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and this is what I have currently with my stream

```
    Files.walk(path)
            .filter(this::shouldChange)
            .forEach(p -> {
                try {
                    String fileName = p.getFileName().toString();
                    Charset charset = StandardCharsets.UTF_8;
                    String content = new String(Files.readAllBytes(p), charset);
                    boolean contentChanged = false;
                    int count = countMatches(content, getName(oldName, '1'));
                    if (count > 0) {
                        content = replaceName(count,
                                getName(oldName, '1'),
                                fileName,
                                getName(newName, '1'),
                                content);
                        contentChanged = true;
                    }
                    count = countMatches(content, getName(oldName, '2'));
                    if (count > 0) {
                        content = replaceName(count,
                                getName(oldName, '2'),
                                fileName,
                                getName(newName, '2'), content);
                        contentChanged = true;
                    }
                    if (contentChanged) {
                        Files.write(p, content.getBytes(charset));
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            });
```

What I am trying to do is try to get rid of the duplicate code which is the following.

```
                    int count = countMatches(content, getName(oldName, '1'));
                    if (count > 0) {
                        content = replaceName(count,
                                getName(oldName, '1'),
                                fileName,
                                getName(newName, '1'),
                                content);
                        contentChanged = true;
                    }
                    count = countMatches(content, getName(oldName, '2'));
                    if (count > 0) {
                        content = replaceName(count,
                                getName(oldName, '2'),
                                fileName,
                                getName(newName, '2'), content);
                        contentChanged = true;
                    }
                    if (contentChanged) {
                        Files.write(p, content.getBytes(charset));
                    }
```

What I would assume is what I can do is make the replace in new method and then `map` it to the stream but that way I cant tract of the `contentChanged` variable. But I don't know how to go about this, So far I only have the stream and filter laid out.

Comment: Can you refactor this code block into a method like `processMatches(content, oldNmae, newNmae, fileName,1)` that returns  say `Pair<Boolean, String>` ?

Comment: I don't see any relationship between the loop code and the stream code.

Comment: Can you explain what the expressions like `getName(oldName, '1')` or `getName(newName, '2')` are supposed to do? There is no `oldName` nor `newName` declared or assigned in this code, so if these inputs are never changing during the entire operation, there is no no reason to repeat these operations multiple times for each file.

Comment: @Holger they are global variables, I am trying to replace everystring in a file that matches oldName seeded with `1` or `2` with newName

Comment: That still sounds like “oldName seeded with 1 or 2” does not need to get recomputed multiple times per file.

Comment: @Holger It needs to get recomputed once for both seeds per file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private String replaceName(String content, String fileName, char ch) {
    if (countMatches(content, getName(oldName, ch)) > 0)
        content = replaceName(count, getName(oldName, ch), fileName, getName(newName, ch), content);

    return content;
}

Files.walk(path)
     .filter(this::shouldChange)
     .forEach(p -> {
         try {
             String fileName = p.getFileName().toString();
             final String content = new String(Files.readAllBytes(p), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
             String changedContent = replaceName(content, fileName, '1');
             changedContent = replaceName(content, fileName, '2');

             if (!content.equals(changedContent))
                 Files.write(p, content.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
         } catch(IOException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
         }
     });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (char i = '1'; i < '3'; ++i) {
    int count = countMatches(content, getName(oldName, i));
    if (count > 0) {
        content = replaceName(count,
                getName(oldName, i),
                fileName,
                getName(newName, i),
                content);
        contentChanged = true;
    }
 }
```